# Deploying Angular Dart component with canvas via shadowRoot: what is missing?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have an angular dart application with a component using canvas via a shadowroot. This runs fine with Dartium, "run as javascript" and pub serve. However when I run pub build and launch the html file in build/web, the component does not appear. The code is at

https://github.com/siddhartha-gadgil/mathlets

Should I be using some special transformers, or do something different to build as against serve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your project and it appears to be working fine.

What I have done in the past is run pub build and hit the built file in dartium and that will not work.  So you have to hit the build file from chrome proper.  So if I load .../mathlets/build/web/mathlets.html  in chrome it works fine.

The reason for this is because `pub build` is the release build, which does not copy any of the dart files. However the index file still has the check if dart is enabled than try to use dart files.  Well in dartium dart is enabled but the build doesn't have the dart files.  In chrome dart is not enabled so then that 'packages/browser/dart.js' file dynamically writes the mathletes.dart.js to index and launches the app that way.

If you want to work around this and improve performance of the release build at the same time you can use this transformer: http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dart_to_js_script_rewriter

We are using this also.  Ensure it's the last transformer run though, if it's before the angular transformer there are problems.

Comment: Clicking a link loading "file:/// " does not work even in chrome, I assume for similar reasons (or something to do with default file names in this case". However scp of the directory to an actual server does the job.

Comment: Ahh, that's also something I forget about.  I use IntelliJ 13 which gives me a local web server to hit through, localhost:XXXX kind of a thing.  FYI you can also run `pub serve` in the release build mode: `pub serve --mode=release` and that would serve it in the same way that `pub build` builds the files.